# Can I use a variable as a value for an attribute of class?

Tags: jquery, css

In the last line, I'm trying to use a variable to identify one specific div which shares the same class (but different target properties) with the other divs involved in the function.

```
$(".nexthotel").click(function(){
    var numhotels= $("#hotels > div").length;
    for(i = 0; i < numhotels; i++){
        if($("#hotel"+i).is(":visible")){
           var x = i + 1;
           $("#hotel"+i).hide();
           $("#hotel"+x).show();
           $(".slidehotels[target= x]").css({"background-color":"cadetblue","color":"#FFF","border":"2px solid cadetblue"});
```

If I change `$(".slidehotels[target= x]")` for `$(".slidehotels[target= 4]")` the div with `target=4` changes its format without problem.

I don't know if it's not possible to give a variable as a value in this case, or if I am just writing the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$(".nexthotel").click(function(){
var numhotels= $("#hotels > div").length;
for(i = 0; i < numhotels; i++){
    if($("#hotel"+i).is(":visible")){
       var x = i + 1;
       $("#hotel"+i).hide();
       $("#hotel"+x).show();
       $(".slidehotels[target=" + x + "]").css({"background-color":"cadetblue","color":"#FFF","border":"2px solid cadetblue"});
```